# Using the Crypto API in the Linux Kernel on a file

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptoapi

I have been trying to use the crypto api in the linux kernel, what i need to do is sha a file that is being opened.  I am using the LSM to catch those file opens.

What I have so far is creating a struct crypto_shash using

```
struct crypto_shash *tfm;
struct shash_desc desc;
tfm = crypto_alloc_shash("sha1", 0, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);
```

and i assume i am supposed to init it after that using

```
desc.tfm = tfm;
desc.flags = 0;

err = crypto_shash_init(&desc);
```

that all works fine, but then i want to use

```
crypto_shash_digest(&desc, ??, ??, sha_hash);
```

and i realize that it expects a scatterlist as its second argument and the length of that scatter list as the third argument.  What i cant figure out is how I am supposed to load the file into a scatterlist in order to give it to the crypto system.

I have done quite a bit of reading but have thus far been unable to find any details about getting a files contents loaded into a scatterlist. So any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar some time ago. The only difference is that I calculated a hash of ELF sections.

1. Probably your desc.flags should be CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP until you have really good reason to prevent crypto operation from blocking.
2. Are you sure you didn't confuse [crypto_shash_digest](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/shash.c#L172) with [crypto_hash_digest](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/crypto.h#L1199)? Because crypto_**s**hash_digest() receives a pointer to data as its 3rd argument. If it's not true for you, what linux kenrel version are you talking about?

Comment: i am using 2.6.38 and you are right, i switched to using shash because of various things i had read saying that was what i wanted.  Oddly enough I am still getting null pointer error when i try crypto_shash_digest(&desc, teststr, strlen(teststr), sha_hash);

Comment: also i am checking that the tfm i get is not null and there is no error from init.

Comment: @DigitalPowers May you show me the code, I need to see how you use crypto_shash_digest(), how you initialize TFM and so on? I assume there's an error with preparation of TFM, but I can't say anything until I see the code.

Comment: the code i pasted originally is it, well i have a call to final at the end and error checking but other than that those are my calls to crypto_shash functions. I am currently using a string literal teststr to try and hash that as a digest, then do final.

Comment: @DigitalPowers 1) Have you tried to set CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP TFM flag? 2) How do you allocate sha_hash? It must be least crypto_shash_digestsize bytes. 3) Where exactly did get nullptr error? Can you show a stack trace?